# How to get the correct output in Modulo (10^9 + 7) format?

Tags: java, modulo

I am working on this code challenge:

> **Problem Description**
>
> Given 2 integers x and n, you have to calculate x
> to the power of n, modulo 10^9+7 i.e. calculate (x^n) % (10^9+7).
>
> In other words, you have to find the value when x is raised to the
> power of n, and then modulo is taken with 10^9+7.
>
> a%b means the remainder when a divides b. For instance, 5%3 = 2, as
> when we divide 5 by 3, 2 is the remainder.
>
> Note that 10^9 is also represented as 1e9.
>
> **Input format**
> One line of input containing two space separated
> integers, x and n.
>
> **Output format** Print the required answer.
>
> **Sample Input 1** 100000000 2
>
> **Sample Output 1** 930000007
>
> **Explanation 1** (10^8)^2 = 10^16
>
> 10^16 % (10^9+7) = 930000007
>
> **Constraints** 0 <= x < 10^9
>
> 0 <= n < 10^5

**Code**

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class ModularExponentiation {
    // NOTE: Please do not modify this function
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int ans = modularExponentiation(x, n);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    // TODO: Implement this method
    static int modularExponentiation(int x, int n) {
        int M = 1000000007;
        long a = (long) Math.pow(x, n);

        long b = a%M;

        return (int)b;
    }
}
```

When I run my code, it succeeds for the sample test case and an edge case, but fails for 3 base cases. How do I make my code succeed all test cases?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `long b = a/M;`, what do you think the `a/M` part means? What will be calculated? Where the assignment says "you have to calculate x to the power of n, modulo 10^9+7 i.e. calculate (x^n) % (10^9+7).", what is your understanding of what the "modulo" part means? (Hint: why do you think a `%` sign is used in the assignment? Do you know what `%` does in a Java program?)

Comment: You have lost precision in `Math.pow` call. `double` can represent exact integer value up to `2**53` ~ `1e15` when you are trying to compute `1e16`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I made a typo, should have done long b = a%M.

However, when I do this, while I do get the desired output for the given sample test case, the code does fail for some base test cases.

Comment: You might give a thought on what 999999999^99999 is, and if you can use `long` to deal with that.

Comment: Note the range: it is possible that you will have to raise `1e9` into `10000` power which is `1e90000` this huge number is by far over `double` MaxValue. That's why naive `Math.pow` will not do.

Comment: Check out  `BigInteger`.  It has a modulus power method and can handle arbitrarily sized ints.  Or check out a book or number theory and employ some potential optimizations/short cuts.

Comment: Next time, you might want to do a little research. All it takes is a web search.  Check out [Modular Exponentiation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/) for explanations and code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```java
    public static int modularExponentiation(int x, int n) {
        int modulo = 1000000007;
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            return x % modulo;
        } else if (n == -1) {
            return 1 / x;
        }
        int p = modularExponentiation(x, n >> 1);
        long product = ((long) p * p) % modulo;
        return (int) (product * modularExponentiation(x, n & 1) % modulo);
    }
```

---

Key points:

1. Math.pow(x,n) suffers from overflow and we can't compensate that overflow relying on result only, that is why initial idea of `Math.pow(x,n) % modulo` produces wrong results
2. We may notice that `(x * x) % modulo == (x % modulo) * (x % modulo) % modulo`, and it is safe to use `long` here as intermediate result because `x % modulo < modulo` and `modulo * modulo < 2^63 - 1`
3. We need to reconstruct the process, but naive approach that `x^n` is a product of `n` x's is too slow - it has O(N) time complexity, however we may notice that `x^2k == (x^k)^2` and `x^(2k+1) == x * (x^k)^2` - so we may use either recursion here or loop to achieve O(LogN) time complexity

alternative loop solution:

```java
    public static int modularExponentiation(int x, int n) {
        int modulo = 1000000007;
        long product = 1;
        long p = x;
        while (n != 0) {
            if ((n & 1) == 1) {
                product = product * p % modulo;
            }
            p = (p * p % modulo);
            n >>= 1;
        }
        return (int) product;
    }
```

Comment: For this particular exercise, `n == -1` is not necessary for the constraints of `0 <= n < 10^5`

Comment: I have flagged your comment as "unfriendly or unkind", cause if you read Q you should know the TC was experiencing difficulties with test cases, but not shared them.

Comment: what line is not clear to you? recursion or the fact that `x^(2k+1) = x * (x^k)^2`

Comment: "with modular exponentiation there is often a requirement to treat negative exponents in accordance with Fermat's Little Theorem" - who cares about that when the problem is "given 2 integers x and n, you have to calculate x to the power of n, modulo 10^9+7 i.e. calculate (x^n) % (10^9+7)"?

Comment: "If you pass 0 and -1 it will blow up for division by 0" - what is analogue of Double#POSITIVE_INFINITY in case of integer arithmetic? ArithmeticException? "why return x % modulus instead of just x when n == 1" - try to pass (java.lang.Integer#MAX_VALUE, 1)

Answer (score -1):

If you have problem in C++ then , you can use

const unsigned int Mod=1e9+7;

Comment: The question isn't asking about C++.