# Java Pow Of 2 Gives me a Wrong answer

Tags: java, exponential, pow

```
class Solution {
    int mod = (int) (1e9) + 7;

    int modPow(long base, long exponent) {
        if (exponent == 0) return 1;

        long result = 1;
        while (exponent > 0) {
            if (exponent % 2 == 1) {
                result = (result * base) % mod;
            }
            base = (base * base) % mod;
            exponent /= 2;
        }
        return (int) result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        int result = solution.modPow(2, (long) 1e9);
        System.out.println(result); // Output: 336781474
    }
}
```

Could you please find the error:
I got the wrong answer as: 140625001
but the correct output is: 336781474

Comment: I have not run your code, but I have to wonder if you're experiencing long overflow. Have you used a debugger to see what the variables are doing as the code runs?

Comment: [And what have you already done in terms of debugging, yourself?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you, please, tell us what the code is *supposed* to do? Even if  it should be obvious, describing what is expected is part of writing a good question.

Comment: If the problem comes from a web page, such as a programming practice / challenge site, please provide a link to that page.

Comment: Does anything on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830171/how-to-get-the-correct-output-in-modulo-109-7-format) help?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Answer (score -4):

Likely a precision error, try to use `long` rather than `int` and if that still does not give you the right answer use `BigInteger` which is an arbitrary precision number.