# The multiplicative formula for calculating the Binomial Coefficient in Java for large n and k values modulo 10^9 + 7 outputs incorrect value

Tags: java, combinatorics

I have an assignment that asks to create a program that can calculate the binomial coefficient given any n, k such that 1<=k<=n<=2000. I am able to accomplish this for small n, k, but for some reason its not accurate at larger n and k values.

Here is my current code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static double bCoeffModded(double nPar, double kPar, double mPar) {
        if ((nPar == kPar) || (kPar == 0)) {
            return 1;
        }
        
        double binomialCoefficient = nPar;
        
        for (int i = 2; i <= kPar; i++) {
            binomialCoefficient *= ((nPar + 1 - i) / i);
            binomialCoefficient %= mPar;
        }
        return binomialCoefficient;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declarations
        double n, k;
        double m = (int) Math.pow(10,9) + 7; // modulus
        int c;
        
        // Input
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        n = reader.nextInt();
        k = reader.nextInt();
        
        // Calculations
        c = (int) bCoeffModded(n, k, m);
        
        // OutPut
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

I am applying the modulus in each iteration because it reduces the chance for an overflow. I think there is an overflow anyway because the accuracy is dropping anyways.

The formula and a overview of the binomial coefficient can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). I should note I already tried the recursive method and factorial method. Both have overflow issues as well.

test case 1:
6 4
**expected** 15
**actual** 15

test case 2:
100 50
**expected** 538992043
**actual** 309695578

Comment: By the way, You may hard code `10 ^ 9 + 7` as `1_000_000_007`.

Comment: You are almost surely running into loss of precision (i.e. rounding errors) in float calculations.  Please see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)  `double` can represent very large numbers, but with limited precision.  `1E30` and `1E30+1` are indistinguishable.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using doubles for this.  Use ints or longs.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this won't work if OP changes all the doubles to ints or longs, because they'll get an integer division inside the `for` loop.  They'll also need to fix the `*=` operation.  This algorithm looks OK to me, but the first line inside the loop probably needs to be `binomialCoefficient = binomialCoefficient * (nPar + 1 - i) / i;` where all the variables are `long`.  That forces the multiplication to happen before the division, which removes the integer division problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if you can divide `x` by `y` that does not mean you can divide `mod(x,k)` by `y`, the idea of getting remainder of intermediate result is wrong when we use division.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov That's true in general, yes, but `10^9+7` happens to be prime, and since one of the conditions of the question is `n <= 2000`, in THIS PARTICULAR CASE, the division will always come out to an integer, provided you multiply first.

Comment: that does not make sense whether it is prime or not, imagine you got `1_000_000_008` at previous step and the next divisor is `2`, that is obvious you will get the wrong result on the next step if you perform modulo division.

Comment: Just switching to longs won't help, the problem is both `*= ((nPar + 1 - i) / i)` and `%= mPar` operations may produce **wrong result**. Another formula which does not involve division is required, for example `(n,k)=(n-1,k-1)+(n-1,k)`

Comment: Ah yes, I spoke too hastily.  I retract my earlier position.  @AndreyB.Panfilov is absolutely right - we can't just simulate modular division by doing integer division and hoping for the best.  We could use the `BigInteger` class, which has a `modInverse` method, so we could invert the divisor and multiply.  Or we could use the recursive formula, which requires lots of additions.  It's unclear to me which would perform better - perhaps some experimentation is in order.

Comment: I changed the *= to binomialCoefficient * (nPar + 1 - i)/i and it got closer to the expected result of (100, 50) just like Dawood ibn Kareem suggested. The result was 500657818.

Comment: Just like some suggested, there is a recurssive form that uses addition. I tried that solution but it just gets stuck and times out for the second test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as I have mentioned in comments, you can't use integer division together with modular division, otherwise you will get wrong results. That means you need to find some kind of recurrent relation or algorithm which does not involve division, I do see following options:

**I**. the obvious recurrent relation is based on Pascal triangle:

`(n,k) = (n-1,k-1) + (n-1,k)`

it does not involve division, hence we may perform our computations using following idea:

`mod((n,k),m) = mod((n-1,k-1),m) + mod((n-1,k),m)`

The problem is, the best time complexity we may achieve there is ~ `O(n*k)`, moreover, we need some sufficient amount of memory to store either intermediate results or call stack.

```java
public static int ncr(int n, int r) {
    // todo: could be optimized to O(r) space
    int[][] interim = new int[n + 1][r + 1];
    return ncr(n, r, interim);
}

public static int ncr(int n, int r, int[][] interim) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;
    if (r == 0 || n == r) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (interim[n][r] > 0) {
        return interim[n][r];
    }
    return interim[n][r] = (ncr(n - 1, r - 1, interim) + ncr(n - 1, r, interim)) % modulo;
}
```

However, I do believe this approach (with some obvious optimizations) is the only one relevant from programmer perspective - others require to perform some research or existence of math background.

**II**. math solution

by definition:

`(n,k)` = `n*(n-1)*..*(n-k-1)/(1*2*..*k)`

here we do know how to calculate `mod(n*(n-1)*..*(n-k-1),m)` and that seems not to be a big deal:

`mod(mod(mod(n,m)*mod(n-1,m),m)*mod(n-2,m),m)....`

the actual challenge is what to do with `1/(1*2*..*k)` part, and the main idea is: is it possible to replace division in `mod(p/q, m)` by multiplication, i.e. find some `r` that satisfies following equality: `mod(p/q, m) = mod(p*r, m)`? And the answer is: yes, it is possible - according to Fermat theorem it is `pow(q,m-2)`, technically we may even calculate `mod(pow(q,m-2),m)` with [`O(logm)` time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72830791/3426309):

```java
public static int modpow(int x, int n) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;
    long product = 1;
    long p = x;
    while (n != 0) {
        if ((n & 1) == 1) {
            product = product * p % modulo;
        }
        p = (p * p % modulo);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return (int) product;
}

public static int ncr(int n, int r) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;

    long mult = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > n - r; i--) {
        mult = (mult * i) % modulo;
    }
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++) {
        mult = (mult * modpow(i, modulo - 2)) % modulo;
    }

    return (int) mult;
}
```

However, as was actually mentioned by @Dawood ibn Kareem in comments: `BigInteger#modInverse` does return something usefull as well and we may rewrite previous code using following form (which is slower than the previous one):

```java
public static int ncr(int n, int r) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;
    BigInteger bm = BigInteger.valueOf(modulo);

    long mult = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > n - r; i--) {
        mult = (mult * i) % modulo;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++) {
        mult = (mult * BigInteger.valueOf(i).modInverse(bm).intValue()) % modulo;
    }

    return (int) mult;
}
```

on the other hand, that is too java specific and most probably we need to "find" another idea of calculating modular inverse, and [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) comes to the rescue:

```
function inverse(a, n)
    t := 0;     newt := 1
    r := n;     newr := a

    while newr ≠ 0 do
        quotient := r div newr
        (t, newt) := (newt, t − quotient × newt) 
        (r, newr) := (newr, r − quotient × newr)

    if r > 1 then
        return "a is not invertible"
    if t < 0 then
        t := t + n

    return t
```

which in our case could be simplified to the following recurrent relation (note, since `m % x < x` we may use dynamic programming approach):

```
inv(x) = (inv(m % x) * (m - m/x)) % m
```

and now we get:

```
public static int ncr(int n, int r) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;

    long mult = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > n - r; i--) {
        mult = (mult * i) % modulo;
    }

    int[] invs = new int[r + 1];
    invs[0] = 1;
    if (r > 1) {
        invs[1] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++) {
        invs[i] = (int) (((long) invs[modulo % i] * (modulo - modulo / i)) % modulo);
        mult = (mult * invs[i]) % modulo;
    }

    return (int) mult;
}
```

---

UPD. It seems I have missed the obvious optimization, and the fastest solution among suggested is actually following (no knowledge of extended Euclidean algorithm required):

```java
public static int modpow(int x, int n) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;
    long product = 1;
    long p = x;
    while (n != 0) {
        if ((n & 1) == 1) {
            product = product * p % modulo;
        }
        p = (p * p % modulo);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return (int) product;
}

public static int ncr(int n, int r) {
    int modulo = 1000000007;

    long mult = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > n - r; i--) {
        mult = (mult * i) % modulo;
    }

    long div = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= r; i++) {
        div = (div * i) % modulo;
    }

    //int modInverse = BigInteger.valueOf(div).modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(modulo)).intValue();
    //return (int) ((mult * modInverse) % modulo);
    return (int) ((mult * modpow((int) div, modulo - 2)) % modulo);
}
```